How to Send a Code Snippet with Rich Formatting Using Microsoft Teams Bot
I’m developing a Microsoft Teams bot, and one of its key features is sending bash scripts as part of the bot’s response for users to execute.
According to the Microsoft Teams documentation on bot message formats, I’m sending the following message (with 3 backticks at the start and the end):
echo 123

However, instead of getting the expected rich code block with syntax highlighting and a "Copy" button, the message just appears as a simple quote, like this:

But, when I manually type the same snippet in a regular Teams chat, it renders correctly with the highlighted code block and "Copy" button:

How can I modify my bot's response to achieve the rich view formatting with syntax highlighting and the "Copy" button for code snippets?
Any guidance on what I'm missing would be greatly appreciated!

Please note that as mentioned in the doc, bot message formatting only supports the following format(text) for preformatted text which renders as a simple quote - https://i.sstatic.net/AJt1tqQ8.png. Currently is not supported in bot message formatting. is only supported with Teams UI.
